# Command Line Uninstall - OpenVPN-2.4.7-I603

Tags: powershell, command-line, uninstallation, openvpn

*SOLVED*

---

### Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\Uninstall.exe" -ArgumentList "/S /qn"

I have been tasked with installing OpenVPN-Connect-3.0.0.272 on our 150+ remote users Windows 10 machines. The issue is that the previous version installed, OpenVPN-2.4.7-I603 is not uninstalling silently through command line; more specifically, Powershell ISE script.

1. I have attempted uninstalling it directly by getting the name through installed applications:

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product

but OpenVPN does not appear as an installed program on the list, therefore it cannot be selected to uninstall.

2. I noticed that in "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\" there is an "Uninstall.exe" file that runs manually, so thinking along those lines:

msiexec.exe /x "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\Uninstall.exe" /qn

and receive error "This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package."

3. Uninstall attempt via

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\Uninstall.exe" -ArgumentList "/s /qn"

successfully launches the uninstall GUI but silent mode is not enabled so it requires user interface.

4. Attempting to uninstall via UninstallString GUID found in

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\OpenVPN

only has a value data of "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\Uninstall.exe" and not a GUID.

What am I missing so this can be uninstalled silently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's different for each program.  My google fu suggests "Uninstall.exe /S".  https://silent-install.net/software/openvpn_technologies/openvpn/2.4.6

Comment: Thank you so much! Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\Uninstall.exe" -ArgumentList "/S /qn" worked.